# what is the the difference between #{path} and "#{RAILS_ROOT}"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that `RAILS_ROOT` is the old way of getting `Rails.root` and that it returns a string while `Rails.root` returns a Pathname object. I have had issues using `RAILS_ROOT` before loading the environment. As a quick solution I use `#{path}` which works and returns also the root path as a tring. I have also noticed that while `RAILS_ROOT` and Rails.root work as expected on console, `#{path}` does not.

So what is this `#{path}` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is not a "path" variable set by default.  Do a search on your code base for "path" and see where it is being set.